# How to take span data by clicking on the anchor tag those are wrapped in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have creating a dynamic `div` using jQuery. That div will wrapping two elements 1. is `<span>` 2. is `<a>` the code be like below:-

```js
$("div").delegate(".dateEdit", "click", function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert(this.id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class= "specific">
      <span id= "0">some data of 1</span>
      <a class="dateEdit" id="0" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
       button
      </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class= "specific">
      <span id= "1">some data of 2</span>
      <a class="dateEdit" id="1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
      button
      </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">  
  <div class= "specific">
      <span id= "3">some data</span>
      <a class="dateEdit" id="3" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
       button
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

How will I take the text of the particular span by clicking its anchor tag and how will show the alert box only once time using this div without using `$('.specific')`. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `$(this).prev('span')`.

Please note: The `on()` syntax is the new syntax  as of jQuery 1.7 and it was meant to substitute  `bind()`, `delegate()` and `live()`.

```js
$("body").on("click", ".dateEdit", function(e){
  //e.preventDefault();
  alert($(this).prev('span').text());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class= "specific">
      <span id= "0">some data of 1</span>
      <a class="dateEdit" id="0" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
       button
      </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">
  <div class= "specific">
      <span id= "1">some data of 2</span>
      <a class="dateEdit" id="1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
      button
      </a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="content">  
  <div class= "specific">
      <span id= "3">some data</span>
      <a class="dateEdit" id="3" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
       button
      </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the closest div and find the span in that div and get the text of that span.

```js
$("div .dateEdit").click(function(e){
    var spanData = $(this).closest('.specific').find('span').text();
    console.log(spanData);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div class="content">
    <div class= "specific">
        <span id= "0">some data of 1</span>
        <a class="dateEdit" id="0" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
         button
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class="content">
    <div class= "specific">
        <span id= "1">some data of 2</span>
        <a class="dateEdit" id="1" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
        button
        </a>
    </div>
 </div>
    
  <div class="content">  
    <div class= "specific">
        <span id= "3">some data</span>
        <a class="dateEdit" id="3" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#thirdModal">
         button
        </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```